# Can an if statement have multiple conditions like this? if yes, how can I separate them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class soundspPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource firstsound;
    public AudioSource secondsound;
    public bool alreadyPlayed = false;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player" , !alreadyPlayed) 
        {
            firstsound.Play();
            secondsound.Play();
            alreadyPlayed = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

I need two sounds to play on trigger but I only want to play them once and only when an object with the "Player" tag enters.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?

Comment: Do you mean `&&`?

Comment: Use the `&&` operator.

Comment: `collider.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !alreadyPlayed`

Answer (score 3):

No, the syntax is either:

```
if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !alreadyPlayed)
```

or

```
if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player" || !alreadyPlayed)
```

`&&` requires both operands to be true, `||` requires only a single operand to be true.

```
 true &&  true == true
 true && false == false
false && false == false
 true ||  true == true
 true || false == true
false || false == false
```

Comment: Can I give this two upvotes?